# emacs bookmark+ :How to create a file specific bookmark file?

Tags: emacs, bookmarks

bookmark+ package provides a `(bmkp-this-file-bmenu-list)` function. This, I suppose, loads a file specific bookmark file and filters only the bookmarks, which relate to the file.

Question: how to create this specific bookmark file for a specific file?

The result should be a filtered list of bookmarks, when using `C-x p ,` command (which is bound to `(bmkp-this-file-bmenu-list)`
).

Edit: I use only one default bookmark file `~/.emacs.d/bookmarks`. This file has some bookmarks for `~/.emacs file`. Now, when I visit, say, `~/.emacs` file, then run `C-x p ,`, I get the following error: `bmkp-this-file-bmenu-list: No bookmarks for file ~/.emacs.`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, actually, command `bmkp-this-file-bmenu-list` does this (from the doc string):

```
Show the bookmark list just for bookmarks for the current file.
Set `bmkp-last-specific-file` to the current file name.
If the current buffer is not visiting a file, prompt for the file name.
```

It shows the `*Bookmark List*` display, listing only and all bookmarks that target the current file.

So if you use this command in a file buffer then you see displayed, in buffer `*Bookmark List*`, all of the bookmarks to the current file, and only those bookmarks.

This has nothing to do with using a different bookmark ***file***.

---

Beyond what this command does, it's not clear to me what behavior you would like. What, for instance, do you mean by a "*specific bookmark file for a specific file*"?

Comment: I use only one default bookmark file `~/.emacs.d/bookmarks`. This file has some bookmarks for `~/.emacs` file. Now, when I visit, say, `~/.emacs` file, then run `C-x p ,`, I get the following error: `bmkp-this-file-bmenu-list: No bookmarks for file ~/.emacs.` But clearly, I have some bookmarks for this file in the default bookmarks file. Therefore, `bmkp-this-file-bmenu-list` likely looks elsewhere for the bookmarks, perhaps, my guess was, in some specific bookmark file for file `~/.emacs` I'm visiting.

Comment: When I use `C-x p ,` when I'm visiting a file, I get a `*Bookmark List*` display showing the bookmarks that target that file. And it sounds like you are doing the same thing but getting an error message. Check to be sure that your bookmark file has in fact been read (loaded), and that it does include at least one bookmark to the file (`~/.emacs`) that you are visiting. (You can check both by doing `C-x r l`.) If so, please send me a bug-report email (`M-x bmkp-send-bug-report`) with as much info as you can dig up about the context. Thx.

Comment: Hi Drew, thanks for fixing this bug in the latest release. I'm accepting your answer, but perhaps you can update your answer, so this question here has a meaningful structure.

Comment: I think there is nothing to update in the question or the answer. The answer describes the intended behavior. A bug was preventing that behavior in your use case, and that is now fixed. Thanks for reporting the bug and helping track down the problem. FWIW (FYI for others: the code here mistakenly used `string=` instead of `bmkp-same-file-p`).

Answer (score 2):

You *can* create a different bookmark file using bookmark+ with `M-x bookmark-load`. You will be prompted for a filename. You can either merge bookmarks from different files or replace the current bookmark set entirely with this fileset by supplying a prefix argument.

Saving bookmarks `bookmark-save` will write all current bookmarks to the current value of the variable `bmkp-current-bookmark-file` , or if you supply a prefix arg you can choose a bookmark filename to save them to.

If you want a set of bookmarks in a distinct file, associated with particular files you could perhaps achieve this by running bookmark-load , and bookmark-save with prefixes. You could probably even automate this with hooks to match your editing contexts, although I expect that would be a little fiddly to achieve.

It sounds like your question might be rooted in some confusion about existing bookmark behaviour, and perhaps you don't even need to maintain separate bookmark files.

Comment: Please see my comment to Drew's answer below. This gives some additional background to my problem.

Comment: yes - what is the value of `bmkp-current-bookmark-file`  ?

Comment: `bmkp-current-bookmark-file is a variable defined in `bookmark+-1.el'.
Its value is "/Users/xxx2/.emacs.d/bookmarks"`

Comment: ok - that looks like it's the value you're expecting it to be, assuming that's the correct path to your .emacs.d